# Rospy Parameter KeyError

Tags: ros, rospy, parameter, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cannot get my code to get the parameters on my config file. I just do like it is on the tutorials but it does not work and I do not understand why. I believe it might be a namespace problem with rospy. I have never had this problem with C++.

My Github with the whole code: https://github.com/renanmb/boat_pid_controller

throttle_interpolator.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy

from std_msgs.msg import Float64
from boat_controller.msg import Drive

# import some utils.
import numpy as np
import copy as copy

class InterpolateThrottle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rpm_input_topic   = rospy.get_param('~rpm_input_topic', '/vesc/commands/motor/unsmoothed_speed')
        self.rpm_output_left_topic  = rospy.get_param('~rpm_output_left_topic', '/vesc/commands/motor/speed_left')
        self.rpm_output_right_topic  = rospy.get_param('~rpm_output_right_topic', '/vesc/commands/motor/speed_right')
        
        self.servo_input_topic   = rospy.get_param('~servo_input_topic', '/vesc/commands/servo/unsmoothed_position')
        self.servo_output_topic  = rospy.get_param('~servo_output_topic', '/vesc/commands/servo/position')
        
        self.max_rpm_acceleration = rospy.get_param('/vesc/max_rpm_acceleration')
        self.max_rpm = rospy.get_param('/vesc/vesc_driver/speed_max')
        self.min_rpm = rospy.get_param('/vesc/vesc_driver/speed_min')
        self.throttle_smoother_rate = rospy.get_param('/vesc/throttle_smoother_rate')
        self.rpm_to_erpm_gain = rospy.get_param('/vesc/rpm_to_erpm_gain')
        
        self.max_servo_speed = rospy.get_param('/vesc/max_servo_speed')
        self.steering_angle_to_servo_gain = rospy.get_param('/vesc/steering_angle_to_servo_gain')
        self.servo_smoother_rate = rospy.get_param('/vesc/servo_smoother_rate')
        self.max_servo = rospy.get_param('/vesc/vesc_driver/servo_max')
        self.min_servo = rospy.get_param('/vesc/vesc_driver/servo_min')

        self.last_rpm = 0
        self.desired_rpm = self.last_rpm
        
        self.last_servo = rospy.get_param('/vesc/steering_angle_to_servo_offset')
        self.desired_servo_position = self.last_servo

        self.rpm_output_left = rospy.Publisher(self.rpm_output_left_topic, Float64,queue_size=1)
        self.rpm_output_right = rospy.Publisher(self.rpm_output_right_topic, Float64,queue_size=1)
        self.servo_output = rospy.Publisher(self.servo_output_topic, Float64,queue_size=1)
        
        rospy.Subscriber(self.rpm_input_topic, Drive, self._process_throttle_command)
        rospy.Subscriber(self.servo_input_topic, Float64, self._process_servo_command)
        
        self.max_delta_servo = abs(self.steering_angle_to_servo_gain * self.max_servo_speed / self.servo_smoother_rate)
        rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(1.0/self.servo_smoother_rate), self._publish_servo_command)
       
        self.max_delta_rpm = abs(self.rpm_to_erpm_gain * self.max_rpm_acceleration / self.throttle_smoother_rate) 

        rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(1.0/self.max_delta_rpm), self._publish_throttle_left_command)
        rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(1.0/self.max_delta_rpm), self._publish_throttle_right_command)
        
        self._run()

    def _run(self):
        rospy.spin()
 
    def _publish_throttle_left_command(self, evt):
        desired_delta = self.desired_rpm_left-self.last_rpm_left
        clipped_delta = max(min(desired_delta, self.max_delta_rpm), -self.max_delta_rpm)
        smoothed_rpm = self.last_rpm_left + clipped_delta
        self.last_rpm_left = smoothed_rpm
        self.rpm_output_left.publish(Float64(smoothed_rpm))
        
    def _publish_throttle_right_command(self, evt):
        desired_delta = self.desired_rpm_right-self.last_rpm_right
        clipped_delta = max(min(desired_delta, self.max_delta_rpm), -self.max_delta_rpm)
        smoothed_rpm = self.last_rpm_right + clipped_delta
        self.last_rpm_right = smoothed_rpm
        self.rpm_output_right.publish(Float64(smoothed_rpm))
            
    def _process_throttle_command(self,msg):
        input_rpm_left = msg.data
        input_rpm_right = msg.data
        input_rpm_left = min(max(input_rpm_left, self.min_rpm), self.max_rpm)
        input_rpm_right = min(max(input_rpm_right, self.min_rpm), self.max_rpm)
        self.desired_rpm_left = input_rpm_left
        self.desired_rpm_right = input_rpm_right

    def _publish_servo_command(self, evt):
        desired_delta = self.desired_servo_position-self.last_servo
        clipped_delta = max(min(desired_delta, self.max_delta_servo), -self.max_delta_servo)
        smoothed_servo = self.last_servo + clipped_delta
        self.last_servo = smoothed_servo         
        self.servo_output.publish(Float64(smoothed_servo))

    def _process_servo_command(self,msg):
        input_servo = msg.data
        input_servo = min(max(input_servo, self.min_servo), self.max_servo)
        self.desired_servo_position = input_servo


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        rospy.init_node('Throttle_Interpolator')
            p = InterpolateThrottle()
        rospy.spin()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/renan/rostest_ws/src/boat_controller/src/throttle_interpolator.py", line 136, in <module>
    p = InterpolateThrottle()
  File "/home/renan/rostest_ws/src/boat_controller/src/throttle_interpolator.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.max_rpm_acceleration = rospy.get_param('/vesc/max_rpm_acceleration')
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 465, in get_param
    return _param_server[param_name] #MasterProxy does all the magic for us
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/msproxy.py", line 123, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: '/vesc/max_rpm_acceleration'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305398/rospy-parameter-keyerror/) by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2018-10-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) on 2018-10-10**:
Is anybody actually loading the parameters from [the yaml](https://github.com/renanmb/boat_pid_controller/blob/dde6498de58437de2fc213e104af7e0372456489/config/vesc.yaml) in the parameter server? Do you have other nodes not in the repo setting them?

If not, you could read them in?

**Comment by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on 2018-10-10**:
My other nodes loads its parameters just fine. I tried the command rosparam load and it does not work. It says the file does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the repo and your own comment it seems you might not be loading the parameters in this node / not running both nodes at the same time?

Given the file a_location.yaml containing:

```
foo:
  bar: [0.194717, -0.592676, 0.042564]
```

The python code to set a generic parameter in rospy should be:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import yaml
import rospy
import rospkg


def load_parameters():
    rospack = rospkg.RosPack()
    path_loc = rospack.get_path("a_pkg") + "/config/a_location.yaml"
    with open(path_loc, 'r') as doc:
        loc = yaml.load(doc)

    x_foo_bar = loc["foo"]["bar"][0]
    y_foo_bar = loc["foo"]["bar"][1]
    z_foo_bar = loc["foo"]["bar"][2]

    rospy.set_param("location", {'x': x_foo_bar, 'y': y_foo_bar, 'z': z_foo_bar})

    # do something


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('my_node', anonymous=True)
    load_parameters()
```

**EDIT**: let's redo the example for vesc.yaml

```
vesc:
  max_rpm_acceleration: 0.123
```

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import yaml
import rospy
import rospkg


def load_parameters():
    rospack = rospkg.RosPack()
    path_loc = rospack.get_path("boat_pid_controller") + "/config/vesc.yaml"
    with open(path_loc, 'r') as doc:
        parameters_vesc = yaml.load(doc)

    max_rpm_accel = parameters_vesc["vesc"]["max_rpm_acceleration"]

    rospy.set_param("max_rpm_acceleration", max_rpm_accel)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('my_node', anonymous=True)
    load_parameters()

    # now that the parameters are loaded you can use them
    p = InterpolateThrottle()
    rospy.spin()
```

---

Originally posted by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) with karma: 589 on 2018-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on 2018-10-10**:
please, I would appreciate if you could provide the source of this information, so I can study it more. To be honest I did not understand anything.

**Comment by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on 2018-10-10**:
I found this: http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/rospy/html/rospy.client-pysrc.html#get_param

But it is pretty much what I was trying to do.

**Comment by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) on 2018-10-11**:
I don't understand if I answered your question. You're using kinetic, so use [those docs](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rospy/html/rospy.client-pysrc.html#get_param). My source is ROS projects on github, e.g. github dot com /Salman-H/pick-place-robot/kuka_arm/scripts/target_spawn.py

**Comment by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on 2018-10-11**:
You did not answer my question, because it still does not work.

I tried to use roslaunch to set all parameter and I created this following question on stackoverflow as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764066/ros-kinetic-error-launching-parameters-cannot-marshal-none-unless-allow-none-is

**Comment by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) on 2018-10-12**:
I answered on stackexchange and edited this answer to provide an example that fits exactly your code.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-12**:\

> I created this following question on stackoverflow as well

why?

**Comment by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on 2018-10-12**:
It was about the launch file, this forum was giving a server error to post another question. I also tried to use the roslaunch to avoid the KeyError.
Thanks for the answer. They do not cite it anywhere on the wiki. So in python I basically have to make that for every parameter.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-12**:
What @aPonza shows is *one particular way to load parameters using the Python API*.

But I would just use a launch file if I were you. That is much more common, better understood and more scalable.

**Comment by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) on 2018-10-12**:
Agreed on the launch file, I arbitrarily assumed OP wanted to stay within the python code.